# How to create a dictionary without using a for loop in 1 line of code?

Tags: python, dictionary

This is my code:

```
dictionary = {}
for i in range(2, 15):
    dictionary[str(i)] = 0
```

Is it possible to create it with just one line of code?

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
print(dict.fromkeys(range(2,15),0))
```

Or if want strings for dictionary keys:

```
print(dict.fromkeys(map(str,range(2,15)),0))
```

Or another way to make keys strings:

```
print(dict.fromkeys([str(i) for i in range(2,15)],0))
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes:

```
dictionary = {str(i): 0 for i in range(2, 15)}
```

This is called a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). There are similar syntax structures for lists, generators, and sets.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another way, you can also make from `zip`:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(range(2,15),iter(int, 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at dictionary comprehension

```
dictionary  = {str(i):0 for i in range(2,15)}
```

Comment: And now, it is L3viathan's answer

Comment: Made the change, but as you pointed out, now its L3viathan's answer :)